# BizTalk Mapping supress empty attribute in the destination

Tags: xslt, mapping, biztalk

I have a case in BizTalk where I want to map an "Attribute Node" which type is Date that can't be null or empty and to avoid problems I need to suppress in the destination transformation map when the source is null.

I followed this link to try the same thing that we do with Nodes but doesn't answer my problem.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/4ab184e0-c978-429c-a80d-e869732de8a2/how-to-suppress-empty-nodes-in-biztalk-map?forum=biztalkgeneral

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you,

Roberto

> Edited
>
> The link didn't mentioned that the Logical String returns True or Nill depending on your source.
>
> I've obliged to check if is empty and as well null

Answer (score 1):

From the source, connect to a Length Functoid, then Greater Than 1 Functoid.

Connect the Greater Than Functoid to the target.

However you end up composing it, connecting a Functoid that returns a boolean is treated as a create yes/no regardless of any value also mapped.

Comment: Only one think, I forgot that Logical String return True when validating the field empty, but return null when the field if nill.

Comment: @RobertoBorges For clarity, I did not recommend using Logical String.  I recommend using Length + Greater Than.

Comment: You solution is more complete, validate any type of value, null or empty. thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use two functoids.
First functoid should be the String Size and the second in line should be the greater than, set on the second functoid the value 0.
Then connect the second functoid to the output element. So if an empty element will be on the source , no empty element will be on the output.